# parsing a text file in javascript? Or something better?

Tags: javascript, parsing, text

I am wondering how I might parse a text file in Javascript and create counts for each item in the text file. Example, a text file that contains:

apple
orange
banana
apple
apple
peach

and the output I want to collect is something like:

apple 3
orange 1
banana 1
peach 1

Javascript might not be the best since this is literally millions of rows like this. I could do it in something else like PHP and store the results in MySQL too. I want to run this routine as items are added to the file and snapshot the results after each run for historical comparison.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: JavaScript is not the best solution unless you are running it with node.js

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like work for a database. You could count the items in a database table in milliseconds, while parsing a text file using compiled code would take seconds, and using client side Javascript would take several minutes.

A database query to group and count the items is quite simple:

```
select Fruit, count(*)
from FruitTable
group by Fruit
```

#### Edit:

I created a test table in SQL Server with 8 million records, and the above query runs in about three seconds.

Comment: +1 After re-reading the post, I think this is a good answer: "store the results in MySQL too .. run this routine as items are added .. snapshot the results after each run"

Answer (score 0):

This is with PHP

```
$string = file_get_contents ("textfile.txt");

$string_array = explode("\n",$string); foreach($string_array as $value) {
        if(isset($str_count[$value]))
                $str_count[$value]++;
        else
                $str_count[$value]=1; } foreach($str_count as $key => $value)
        echo $key.": ".$value."<br>";
```

**textfile.txt:**

```
apple
orange
banana
apple
apple
peach
```

**Output:**

```
apple: 3
orange: 1
banana: 1
peach: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use perl, an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $file   = shift;
my %fruits = ();

open(my $handle, "<", $file);

while(defined(my $fruit = <$handle>)) {
        chomp $fruit;
        $fruits{$fruit}++;
}

foreach my $key (sort keys %fruits) {
        print "$key: ", $fruits{$key}, "\n";
}
```

then run it with `perl fruits.pl FILENAME_TO_FRUITS_FILE`

ultimately, the above is the easiest way to do it, but you really should move it to a database if you do have *millions* of entries. any simple PHP/MySQL tutorial will be helpful.

Comment: I had not thought about Perl at all, thanks for making me think about this as a solution

Comment: perl is a great language if you're working with text manipulation. it's a tool you should always keep on your belt.

Comment: Do you have a good Perl tutorial so I can get back up to speed? I forgot how powerful it can be for stuff like this!

Comment: could I output the results of the perl to its own text file easily?

Comment: Wow Perl has a MySQL Module. This setup could be really awesome as I have a lot of manipulation to do.